# Assets/Scripts/CameraOperator.cs(73,45): error CS0103: The name `hit' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a RTS style game and I fixed some errors now I got more errors. Can someone please help?

> Assets/Scripts/CameraOperator.cs(71,25): error CS0131: The left-hand
>   side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer
>
> Assets/Scripts/CameraOperator.cs(73,45): error CS0103: The name `hit'
>   does not exist in the current context

Here is the script, and any help would br great.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CameraOperator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D selectionHighlight = null;
    public static Rect Selection = new Rect (0, 0, 0, 0);
    private Vector3 StartClick = -Vector3.one;
    private static Vector3 moveToDestination = Vector3.zero;
    private static List<string> passables = new List<string> () {"Floor"};

    private void Update ()
    {
        CheckCamera ();
        CleanUp ();
    }

    private void CheckCamera ()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
        {
            StartClick = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) 
        {
            StartClick = -Vector3.one;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0))
        {
            Selection = new Rect (StartClick.x, InvertMouseY (StartClick.y), Input.mousePosition.x - StartClick.x, InvertMouseY (Input.mousePosition.y) - InvertMouseY (StartClick.y));
            if (Selection.width < 0) 
            {
                Selection.x += Selection.width;
                Selection.width = -Selection.width;
            }
            if (Selection.height < 0) 
            {
                Selection.y += Selection.height;
                Selection.height = -Selection.height;
            }
        }
    }
    float InvertMouseY (float y)
    {
        return Screen.height - y;
    }

    private void CleanUp ()
    {
        if (!Input.GetMouseButtonUp (1)) {
            moveToDestination = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
    public static Vector3 GetDestination ()
    {
        if (moveToDestination == Vector3.zero) 
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray r = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast (r, out hit)) 
            {
                while (!passables.Contains(hit.transform.gameObject.name))
                {
                    if (!Physics.Raycast (hit.transform.position, r.direction, out hit))
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!hit.transform = null) 
        {
            moveToDestination = hit.point;
        }
        return moveToDestination;
    }
}
```

Comment: Typos are easy to make when your following someones tutorial.

Comment: But the compiler tells you _exactly_ which line the error is occurring on. If you're following a tutorial with that many typos in it, you might want to consider finding a new tutorial. Clearly whoever wrote it wasn't being very careful and is confusing you.

Comment: Yes they confuse me because im still a noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to capitalize the "O" in "`gameobject`". At line 64, in fact, you have `hit.transform.gameobject.name`.